# " " instead of [ ] in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I used a php variable into Javascript like this-

```
var Coordinates = <?php echo json_encode($coords); ?>;
```

And now I want to stringify it so I used

```
var JSON_Coordinates = JSON.stringify(Coordinates);
```

the result is

```
["-98.47442960102632,38.51861967935271","-98.46128420909388,38.17510666712973","-97.91584295178713,38.17274814619617", -"97.91882439611877,38.51683243137235", "-98.47442960102632,38.51861967935271"]
```

But I want It to be like this-

```
[[-98.47442960102632,38.51861967935271],[-98.46128420909388,38.17510666712973],[-97.91584295178713,38.17274814619617], [-97.91882439611877,38.51683243137235], [-98.47442960102632,38.51861967935271]]
```

So how to replace `" "` with `[ ]`?

Comment: This looks like compensating for something that isn't implemented right and possibly not solving the right problem...

Comment: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)... Format the array correctly in PHP before passing it to Javascript instead of trying to juggle the wrong format in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before converting to json in php, you could convert each coords string to an array in a loop, then ensure values are not strings but numeric using JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK

```
<?php
foreach ($coords as &$value) {
    $value = explode(',', $value); // prevent to array like ["23","45"]
}
unset($value); // avoid reuse of &reference variable by mistake
echo json_encode($coords, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked correctly for me after some modifications.

Answer (score 2):

You could fix it on the server side:

```
$coords = array(
    '-98.47442960102632,38.51861967935271',
    '-98.46128420909388,38.17510666712973',
    '-97.91584295178713,38.17274814619617',
    '-97.91882439611877,38.51683243137235',
    '-98.47442960102632,38.51861967935271'
);
$coords = array_map(function($coord) {
    list($lat, $lon) = explode(",", $coord);
    return array((float) $lat, (float) $lon);
}, $coords);
echo json_encode($coords);
```

Output (pretty printed):

```
[
    [-98.474429601026, 38.518619679353],
    [-98.461284209094, 38.17510666713],
    [-97.915842951787, 38.172748146196],
    [-97.918824396119, 38.516832431372],
    [-98.474429601026, 38.518619679353]
]
```